# A definite integral related to sample variances of bivariate Gaussians

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, integration

This integral is needed to obtain the joint
distribution of the sample variances of a random sample from a bivariate
Gaussian distribution. For details on the joint distribution of the sample
means, sample variances, and sample correlation, please see Sections 14.11 to
14.13 of Kendall's book (2nd edition):

*Kendall, Maurice G.*, The Advanced Theory of Statistics. Vol. I, Philadelphia: J. B. Lippincott Co., XI, 457 p. (1944). [ZBL0063.03214](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0063.03214).

The integral is $$ I\left(  n,c\right)
=\int_{-1}^{1}\exp\left(  cr\right)  \left(  1-r^{2}\right)  ^{\left(
n-4\right)  /2}dr,$$

where $c\neq0$ is a constant, and $n\geq4$ is (a constant and) an integer
(and is the sample size). When $n-4$ is even, we can use ``integration by parts'' to get $I\left(  n,c\right)  $ after
some tedious computations. In general, we can use the expansion $$\left(
1-r^{2}\right)  ^{\left(  n-4\right)  /2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k,n}r^{2k},$$
compute each $$s_{k}=\int_{-1}^{1}\exp\left(  cr\right)  a_{k,n}r^{2k}dr,$$ and
then compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}s_{k}$. For this method, we may not have an
explicit, analytic expression for $I\left(  n,c\right)  $.

On the other hand, we can use the expansion $$\exp\left(  cr\right)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{c^{k}r^{k}}{k!},$$ compute $$b_{2k}=2\int_{0}^{1}%
\frac{c^{2k}}{\left(  2k\right)  !}r^{2k}\left(  1-r^{2}\right)  ^{\left(
n-4\right)  /2}dr,$$ and compute $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_{2k}$. Note that each
$b_{2k}$ relates to the Beta function (upon a change of variable $r^{2}%
\mapsto\tau$). But what does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_{2k}$ look like?

Could someone please point me to some references on whether $I\left(
n,c\right)  $ has an explicit, analytic expression, or on whether such an expression can be obtained by one of the attempts mentioned above? Dose this integral involve special functions? Thanks.

Comment: Personally I don't think it's appropriate to post this kind of question without including results from Wolfram Alpha/Mathematica/Maple/Sage.

Comment: Thank you, Neil. Will do that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Wolfram Alpha understands this integral.
Its answers are given 
in terms of [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) $I_k$.

It seems that the result is, for
$A(k,c):=I(n,c)$, with $n-4=2k+1$,

> $$I(n,c)=\frac{(2k+1)!!\cdot \pi\cdot I_{k+1}(c)}{c^{k+1}}.$$

For instance,
$$\begin{eqnarray}I(5,c)&=&A(0,c)=\frac{\pi I_{1}(c)}{c}\\
I(7,c)&=&A(1,c)=\frac{3\pi I_{2}(c)}{c^2}\\
I(9,c)&=&A(2,c)=\frac{5\cdot 3\cdot \pi\cdot  I_{3}(c)}{c^3}\\
I(11,c)&=&A(3,c)=\frac{7\cdot 5\cdot 3\cdot \pi\cdot  I_{4}(c)}{c^4}
\end{eqnarray}$$
The last equation for $I(11,c)$ is verified by Wolfram Alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+e**%28ax%29+%281-x**2%29**%287%2F2%29+dx%2C+x+from-1+to+1).

Comment: Kjos-Hanssen: thank you for pointing out the Bessel function. I think I can get it going by using contour integral by raising the $cos$ function in the definition of the Bessel function to some rational power .

Comment: Prof. Kjos-Hanssen: how did you get the formular? Thank you.

Comment: @Chee just educated guessing based on the Wolfram Alpha answers...

Answer (score 3):

Using  the integral representation of the modified Bessel function $I$ (see [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E2), for example),
$$
I_{\nu}\left(z\right)=\frac{(\frac{1}{2}z)^{\nu}}{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\int_{-1}^{1}(1-t^{2})^{\nu-\frac{1}{2}}e^{\pm zt}\mathrm{d}t
$$
 we find directly
$$I(n,c)=2^{\frac{n-3}{2}}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left( \frac{n}{2}-1 \right)c^{\frac{3-n}{2}}I_{\frac{n-3}{2}}(c)$$

Comment: Paul Enta: thank you for pointing this out, saving me time on computing a contour integral on my own.  Neil Strickland: i am most of the time a statistician, and do not often use Mathematica :)